# Using Workbox via a local copy, without a CDN

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I have a small device that serves a webpage using Nginx in a local network. I'm developing the webpage using Vue and I need that once a person got connected to the server and visited the page, on disconnection, the page needs to work as normal

I'm currently using Workbox plugin and I get this code:

```
importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");

importScripts(
  "/precache-manifest.b62cf508e2c3da8c27f2635f7aab384a.js"
);
```

The problem is that it goes to the internet to download that file and I will not have an internet connection.

I tried downloading this file, but inside goes to the internet again.

Is there a way to get this to work in an offline environment?

Comment: Is this from `service-worker.js`? It gets created with each build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the guidance in the [`workbox-sw` docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-sw) to download a local copy of the bundled Workbox runtime libraries, and modify your service worker script to use those.

Running:

```sh
$ npx workbox-cli@4.3.1 copyLibraries /path/to/dir
```

from the command line will download a local copy of the runtime to the specified directory (replace `/path/to/dir` with the desired location).

You can then modify your service worker script so that it reads:

```js
importScripts("/path/to/dir/workbox-v4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");

workbox.setConfig({
  modulePathPrefix: '/path/to/dir/workbox-v4.3.1/'
});

importScripts(
  "/precache-manifest.b62cf508e2c3da8c27f2635f7aab384a.js"
);
```

Comment: My `service-worker.js` gets recreated at each build, erasing all made chagnes. I use vue3 with webpack, created with the vue CLI.